# Does the size of the gradient decrease in this heat-type equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T>0$. Suppose all functions are smooth and $u$ solves $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x,t)-\Delta u(x,t)+\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^nf_i(x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}(x,t)+g(x)}_{\text{lower order terms}}=0,\quad (x,t)\in\Omega\times(0,T).$$ Do we always have that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\lvert\nabla u(x,t)\rvert^2\leq0$$ for all $(x,t)\in\Omega\times(0,T)$ or are there counterexamples?

Comment: Even for the standard heat equation you don't have such a strong property. You're much better off looking for a maximum principle, i.e. something like $\frac d{dt} \sup_x |\nabla u(x,t)|^2 \le 0$.

Comment: (That exact fact isn't going to be true without conditions on $g$ - with such a driving term even constant initial data will develop gradients. It's just the general form of things that could possibly be true.)

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis You are right about the standard heat equation not satisfying this condition and for some reason I missed that.